# Error when trying to produce a Graph in Plotly Dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

When trying to produce a figure with the following code

```py
@app.callback(
    [
        Output("selected-plot", "figure")
    ],
    [
        Input("submit-selected-plotting", "n_clicks"),
        State("table", "data")
    ],
)
def plot(button_clicked, data)           
    fig = go.Scatter(x=data["index"],
                     y=data["result"],
                     mode='lines',
                     name='result')
    return fig
```

and

```py
            dbc.Col(
                [
                    dcc.Graph(id='selected-plot')
                ],
                width=6,
            )
```

I get a strange error with the app expecting a different object:

> dash._grouping.SchemaTypeValidationError: Schema: [<Output
> `selected-plots.figure`>]
> Path: ()
> Expected type: (<class 'tuple'>, <class 'list'>)
> Received value of type <class 'plotly.graph_objs._scatter.Scatter'>:
> Scatter({...})

I have tried everything but I can't seem to go around this error.
Thanks for any suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that the app expects a figure object, you can fix it by updating the callback as follows:

```py
@app.callback(
    [
        Output("selected-plot", "figure")
    ],
    [
        Input("submit-selected-plotting", "n_clicks"),
        State("table", "data")
    ],
)
def plot(button_clicked, data)     
      
    trace = go.Scatter(
        x=data["index"],
        y=data["result"],
        mode='lines',
        name='result'
    )

    return [go.Figure(data=trace)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately that did not fix the problem. The traceback actually says that a graph object is received, but it expects something different apparently and I have no idea why.

Comment: I think it's because it expects a list. I have just updated my answer, let me know if it works now.

Comment: That worked! I have no idea why it expects a list, as it should not by default, anyway very thankful.

Comment: It's because `Output("selected-plot", "figure")` is enclosed in square brackets, if you remove them then my previous answer will work.